# When to use ところ / て+いるところ / た+ところ

Tags: syntax, tense, jlpt

In this sentence:

> 「もしもし、今、駅に向かって（_______）ところです。 あと５、６分でつきます。」

What should be the correct tense of the verb 歩く?  Should I base my answer on the word 今 or the てform of 向かう?

If there is 今 does that mean that た+ところ is not appropriate?
If I see a Verbてform, all my V should be in てform?

Thank you

Comment: To clarify: do you want to add the verb 歩く into the blank?

Comment: Yes sorry. The verb is 歩く

Answer (score 4):

> 1. 今、駅に向かって歩いているところです。
>      I am walking toward the station. (i.e. I am on the way.)
> 2. 今、駅に向かって歩くところです。
>      I am just about to walk toward the station. (i.e., I have not departed yet.)
> 3. 今、駅に向かって歩いたところです。
>      I have just walked toward the station. (i.e., I have finished walking.)

These three sentences are all at least grammatical, but Sentence 1 is the most natural. Sentence 2 is not entirely wrong, but people usually say something like 今から出発します if they have not departed yet. Sentence 3 doesn't make sense at all in this context.

The existence of 今 is not really important because these sentences describe his *current* situation even without saying 今 (Note all the sentences end with です, which is the present tense). Even in sentence 3, it describes his *current* situation. It's similar to [ている describing the continuation of state](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3122/5010), except that the original action happened shortly before *now* (hence "just").

Related:

- [Can ところで be ambiguous (time vs. location)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/39699/5010)
- [A bunch of questions about ところ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27541/5010)

Comment: Thank you. I am having problems choosing the best answer  Thank you for your help.